# Spark Job with Multiple Contexts is failing

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, amazon-emr, spark-cassandra-connector

In the spark application we are making two spark contexts,

1) For reading data from file system.

2) For connecting and loading data to Cassandra.

In one app we can run only one spark spark context, so we are stopping 1st then starting second.

I was getting the following error.

```
Error 1) 16/03/10 05:40:44 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread      Thread-2
java.io.IOException: Target log file already exists        (hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps/application_1457586850134_0001_2)
    at `org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.stop(EventLoggingListener.scala:225)`
```

It was because , in hadoop the directory/file need not be present when running the job (1st context), so for running 2nd context the log direcory/log file was present 
I So was the above error.

I solved the issue by setting spark.eventLog.overwrite=true

---

```
Error 2) WARN executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: An unknown (ip-10-93-141-13.ec2.internal:48849) driver disconnected. 16/03/10 06:47:37                                                            ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver 10.93.141.13:48849disassociated! Shutting down.
```

I tried increasing the

> spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=1024
>
> spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024

But the problem is still there.

---

Error 3)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.93.141.13:46008
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have checked in in the core node , it is not listening on port 46008.

---

Error 4 )

```
WARN YarnAllocator: Container marked as failed:              container_1457586850134_0006_01_000006 on host: ip-10-164-169-         46.ec2.internal. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-   launch.
Container id: container_1457586850134_0006_01_000006
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
at   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

16/03/10 06:47:17 WARN ApplicationMaster: Reporter thread fails 1 time(s) in a row.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: RpcEnv already stopped.
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.send(NettyRpcEnv.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEndpointRef.send(NettyRpcEnv.scala:516)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator$$anonfun$processCompletedContainers$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(YarnAllocator.scala:531)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator$$anonfun$processCompletedContainers$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(YarnAllocator.scala:512)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator$$anonfun$processCompletedContainers$1.apply(YarnAllocator.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator$$anonfun$processCompletedContainers$1.apply(YarnAllocator.scala:442)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator.processCompletedContainers(YarnAllocator.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator.allocateResources(YarnAllocator.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$1.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:368)
```

The above error is since the container is failing continously.

---

It seems the above  spark issue's due to  multiple contexts, as raised in the mailing list.

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-issues/201602.mbox/%3CJIRA.12936774.1454603470000.316442.1454707659978@Atlassian.JIRA%3E

sparkContext.stop() is not able to free up the resources.

---

I'm running the using the following options

```
--class com.mobi.vserv.driver.Query5kPids                            
  --conf spark.eventLog.overwrite=true  
  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024                       
  --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=1024                             
  --num-executors 4                
  --executor-memory 3g            
  --executor-cores 2                  
  --driver-memory 3g
```

I'm running on EMR , with a master and 2 slave nodes, master has 8 core and 16GB memory and each slave has 4 core 5120 MB available memory.

Below is my code.

```
    public class Query5kPids implements Serializable{

    static List<UserSetGet> ListFromS3 = new ArrayList<UserSetGet>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException {


    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    conf.setAppName("Spark-Cassandra Integration");
    conf.setMaster("yarn-cluster");
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "12.16.193.19");
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042");


    SparkConf conf1 = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkAutomation").setMaster("yarn-cluster");

    Query5kPids app1 = new Query5kPids(conf1);
    app1.run1(file);

    Query5kPids app = new Query5kPids(conf);
    System.out.println("Both RDD has been generated");
    app.run();

   }

   private void run() throws JSONException, IOException, InterruptedException {

   JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
   query(sc);
   sc.stop();
   }

   private void run1(File file) throws JSONException, IOException,     InterruptedException {
   JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
   getData(sc,file);
   sc.stop();

  }

   private void getData(JavaSparkContext sc, File file) {

   JavaRDD<String> Data = sc.textFile(file.toString());
   System.out.println("RDD Count is " + Data.count());

   // Other map opetations to convert to UserSetGet RDD.
   ListFromS3 = Data.collect();

   }
   private void query(JavaSparkContext sc) {

   System.out.prin`enter code here`tln("RDD Count is " +  ListFromS3.size());
   //This gets printed. 
   //Which means it application is coming to the second part of the program.

   for (int i = 0; i < ListFromS3.size(); i++) {

   sb.append(ListFromS3.get(i).getApnid());
   sb.append(',');
   }
   sb.setLength(sb.length() - 3);

   JavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRDD = CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("dmp", "user_profile_spark_test").select       ("app_day_count", "app_first_seen","app_last_seen", "app_usage_count", "total_day_count", "total_usage_count")
 .where("apnid IN ('" + sb + "')");

   if(cassandraRDD.isEmpty()){

   JavaRDD<UserSetGet> rddFromGz = sc.parallelize(ListFromS3);

   CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(rddFromGz).writerBuilder("dmp", "user_profile_spark_test", mapToRow(UserSetGet.class)).saveToCassand();
        logger.info("DataSaved");
   }
   }

   }
```

Below is my POM

```
   <dependencies>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache-extras.cassandra-jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.5</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
   <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.7</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.17</version>
   </dependency>


   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.0</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.0-M1</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.6</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.0-M3</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
   <version>4.1</version>
   </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are running tests with local spark context and are using following "hack" to solve collision problems:

```
sc.stop()
// To avoid Akka rebinding to the same port, since it doesn't unbind 
// immediately on shutdown

System.clearProperty("spark.driver.port")
```

Any reason you are using 2 different spark contexts? Why can't you use only 1?

Comment: Thanks for the answer , shall I call System.clearProperty("spark.driver.port")  before sc.stop() or after it , and sorry for being dumb from where System.clearProperty will pick spark.driver.port ? also I'm using 2 spark contexts since 1st context reads data from file system and second reads from cassandra.

Comment: The reason I had asked since , Im using the default driver port and not giving it explicitly, just to add is it ok If i give it explicitely

Comment: I explicitely gave driver port for both contexts , but now it is giving Failed to connect to /10.230.132.121:51324 , this is the IP of one of the core node. And containers are still failing.

Comment: I'm still not get you. Have you tried to use only 1 context? I understand that you read from hdfs and then from cassandra, but what happens if you'll use same context?
Never gave port explicitly. System.crearProperty("spark.driver.port"); just removes "spark.driver.port" property from registered System properties(which is set by spark context)

Comment: My bad I was under the impression that for reading from HDFS , we need different context :( , but anyways in my next assignment I have to connect to MongoDB and cassandra , So I guess I will have to use two different contexts.

Comment: I'm still not getting , I have to do System.clearProperty("spark.driver.port") in the code after sc.stop() , but then from where do I have to remove spark.driver.port ? Which file ?

Comment: no, imho you can use only 1 context for everything.
in  your code there is sc.stop(); just put System.clearProperty("spark.driver.port") after it...that's all(or just use 1 context)

Comment: Ok thanks , but then I have to create two confs one for mongodb and then for Cassandra , then I will create a Spark Context  object with the conf tied to  Mongodb, but then for 2nd conf which is tied to Cassandra , how will I use that Context Object  again ?

Comment: Juss to add on graceful exit , is it ok If i use addShutdownHook ie  Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() { 
        sc.stop();
        System.clearProperty("spark.drive.port");
        System.out.println("Running Shutdown Hook");
        }
      });

Comment: if your configuration for cassandra and for mongo are not colliding(i.e. they have different properties) then you can have 1 config(unified) for both usages. Regarding shutdown hook, not sure if you need to clear property there, since when you closing your jvm - you won't be able to start another spark context(i.e. this System.clearProperty("spark.drive.port") is needed only when you start spark context - stop it and then start another spark context within same jvm process)

Comment: Thanks a ton Igor :) You are a life saver , I have tested it using one context it worked, just for experiment i'll do System.clearProperty() also , and will share the result, hope question here will help other developers.

Comment: here http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/connectors/spark-1.0/java-api.html , it says to create CouchbaseSparkContext csc = couchbaseContext(sc); from JavaSparkContext , so using this with cassandra will be a problem right.  Please suggest if something can be done using the same context for both cassandra and couchdb

Comment: You can wrap same spark context in coachbase spark context